# problem with action handler of UIBarButtonItems 

Tags: ios, action, uibarbuttonitem

I am facing a very silly problem with my code for buttons in the toolbar. I am using the following code and I already have the action handler functions in the code, but whenever I am clicking on the buttons, I am getting the error: " - [UIWebView function_name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x....." Can anyone kindly help ? Thanks.

inside the .h file:

```
- (void) goBackHandler;
- (void) goForwardHandler;
- (void) goSafari;
```

inside the .m file :

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton=[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goBackHandler)]autorelease];

UIBarButtonItem *forwardButton=[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"forward.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self.webViews action:@selector(goForwardHandler) ] autorelease];    

UIBarButtonItem *safariButton=[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Safari" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goSafari)]autorelease];

UIBarButtonItem *flex=[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]autorelease];

NSArray *arrayOfButtons=[[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:backButton,flex,safariButton,flex,forwardButton, nil]autorelease];

[self setToolbarItems:arrayOfButtons];





- (void) goBackHandler
{

if ([self.webViews canGoBack])
{
    [self.webViews goBack];
}

}

- (void) goForwardHandler
{
if ([self.webViews canGoForward])
{
    [self.webViews goForward];
}
}

- (void) goSafari
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.webViews stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location"]]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because of this line,

```
UIBarButtonItem *forwardButton=[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"forward.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self.webViews action:@selector(goForwardHandler) ] autorelease];
```

You have made `self.webViews` the target but I think you meant `self`.

Answer (score 0):

The Target of a target:action: pair is the object which implements the method specified in the action: parameter. So in this case, your target will be self for each of those buttons.